# Build failed. Problems with android layouts

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-image

I am trying to run my application on android studio, but I get the errors of "build failed". Although if I open a new project it can run the hello world. I haven't done any coding, Just some changes to the layout. added some buttons and background image a two more images. After doing this when I run my application then it will give me the errors. Please help me fix this issue, Thanks

Comment: What errors? With so little information, we can hardly be expected to help.

Comment: O.O.Balance As you have seen the buld tab

Comment: check for open and close xml tag. Check if images are valid. Like @O.O.Balance says, there is so little information about your problem.

Comment: O.O.Balance   When I try to run my application all the errors in the build. The tab at the bottom of android studio it show the errors like build failed, Android issues(1 error), I have tried syncing the gradle but not working for me, and I don't know why I have not written any java code yet, I have just changed the background image and added a logo image, the names of the images are short like "logo". Before adding the images the hello world was run successfully on but after adding two images only, it is giving me errors

Comment: O.O.Balance ;       Can i upload picture, i don't know how I can send you a screen shot to see the errors

Comment: no @ is used in image names. I have only used relative layouts. Separate relative layout is used for logo, and background and other images. that's it. Nothing more is been used.  I have checked the xml code but don't know why giving me the error

Comment: Don't post images of errors. Post the full text of the error.

Comment: Hello O.O Balance thank for your help.  The error status has now changed. It AAPT2 error check log for details

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you are using your old application, just sync the gradle again it will automatically download required files.

Comment: Parveen GM Thank you very much I have already done that but am struggling why its not working for me. I will try gradle sync.